# Protobuf build DynamicMessage with Data Types

Tags: protocol-buffers, prototype, grpc-java, proto

I have a proto with imported Data types.  something similar to:

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message someMessage
    .google.protobuf.StringValue someString = 1;
    .google.protobuf.Int64Value someInt = 2;
    .google.protobuf.DoubleValue someDouble = 3;
```

previously my proto looked like:

```
message someMessage {
    string someString = 1;
```

Prior to adding data types, the code below worked just fine.  Now when I run, I get an error similar to `com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Invalid wrapper type: google.protobuf.StringValue`

```java
DynamicMessage.Builder dynamicMessageBuilder = DynamicMessage.newBuilder(someDescriptor);
JsonFormat.parser().merge(stringPayload, dynamicMessageBuilder);
byte[] blah = dynamicMessageBuilder.build().toByteArray();
```

How do I get my proto messages to build correctly with typed data?

Comment: Could you share the full message definition?

Comment: @ClémentJean Jean What other pieces of information are you looking for from the proto definition?

Comment: mostly the import for StringValue, Int64Value and DoubleValue

Comment: @ClémentJean I added the only import I have in the proto above.  It all works if I use the proto object generated, its just when I try to use the descriptor files.

Comment: @ClémentJean  I think we solved the issue using a type registry.  We need to do a little more testing, and I can provide our solution if it ends up working.

Comment: the thing to note is that these wrappers are messages with a value field inside them.Thus serializing/deserialization a string and a wrapper is not really the same. Expecting your answer to see if I can help improve.

Comment: @ClémentJean  I added our solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello The answer actually lied in a different part of the code:

```
FileDescriptorProto myFile = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(is).getFile(0);
someDescriptor = Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(myFile, new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[]{}).findMessageTypeByName("myMessage");
```

We ended up doing something like this.  Note that the actual solution is dynamic and not hard coded, but it is not as easily unerstood.

```
Descriptors.FileDescriptor valuetypes = Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(fileDescriptorProtoList.get(0), new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[]{});
someDescriptor = Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(fileDescriptorProtoList.get(1), new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[]{valueTypes}).findMessageTypeByName("myMessage");
```

Also note this is important when generating the descriptor files

```
<includeDependenciesInDescriptorSet>true</includeDependenciesInDescriptorSet>
```